# Using regex to capture `\"` and split into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have come across something that I haven't seen before and google is no use because it keeps removing `\"` from my search.

First of all, what does `\"` mean?  I am accessing an API and for one of the key's values it is a string of tags, but then if one of the tags has two words it uses `\"` to show that the tag is two words.  Example below

`"foo bar baz \"taz foo\" goo too loo"`

I am trying to split those up into an array like so `["foo", "bar", "baz", "taz foo", "goo", "too", "loo"]`

However I am having one hell of a time figuring out how to capture the `\"` and making it so I can split them to an array like above.

Comment: You may find this informative:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation

Comment: Thank you that was very informative!

Answer (score 2):

Use [String.prototype.**replace()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for fun and profit:

```
var s = "foo bar baz \"taz foo\" goo too loo";

var arr = [];
s.replace(/[^\s"]+|"[^"]*"/g, function($1) {
  arr.push($1.replace(/"/g,''));
});

console.log(arr); // ["foo", "bar", "baz", "taz foo", "goo", "too", "loo"]
```

---

Create an empty array `arr` to push matches into
Use `replace` to collect `$1` matches: anything that is
`[^\s"]+` not a whitespace or doubleQuote (one or infinite times)
`|` or
`"[^"]*"` anything between `"  "` that is not a quote `[^"]` (zero or infinite times `*`)

Comment: Mind explaining your regular expression a little please ?

Comment: Thanks very much for your explanation it make much sense now.

Answer (score 1):

`\"` means to escape the double quote character. It's called an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).

If you want to use a double inside a string that is double quoted, you will have to use the escape character.

Say for example you want to store a string `abcd"xyz"abcd`

```
console.log("abcd"xyz"abcd");
```

will give you an error because double quotes before `xyz` mark the end of string and quote after `xyz` mark the beginning of new string, hence an error occurs because of improper syntax.

Therefore to have double quotes inside a string you will have to

either escape the double quotes using `\"`

```
console.log("abcd\"xyz\"abcd");
```

or put double quotes inside a single quoted string

```
console.log('abcd"xyz"abcd');
```

As for your splitting question, you can split on a regex to get that array like this:

```
> "foo bar baz \"taz foo\" goo too loo".match(/\w+|(?:")[^"]*?(?:")/g);

["foo", "bar", "baz", ""taz foo"", "goo", "too", "loo"]
```

and then you can iterate over the array and remove double quotes like this:

```
> '"abcd xyz"'.replace(/"/g, '');
"abcd xyz"
```

Combined code:

```
> arr="foo bar baz \"taz foo\" goo too loo".match(/\w+|"[^"]*?(?=")/g);
["foo", "bar", "baz", ""taz foo", "goo", "too", "loo"]
> for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){arr[i]=arr[i].replace(/"/g, '');}
> console.log(arr);
["foo", "bar", "baz", "taz foo", "goo", "too", "loo"]
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with this is that `taz foo` should be one index in the array and not split.

Comment: *"It's called an escape sequence"* No, it's not. An escape sequence is something different. This is just an escaped character. Read the link you posted

Comment: @Borodin yes .. i wanted to refer the [escape sequences in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C) page, but yeah [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) is much more generic